# How do I UPDATE from a SELECT in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update, dml

In **SQL Server**, it is possible to insert rows into a table with an `INSERT.. SELECT` statement:

```
INSERT INTO Table (col1, col2, col3)
SELECT col1, col2, col3 
FROM other_table 
WHERE sql = 'cool'
```

Is it also possible to *update* a table with `SELECT`? I have a temporary table containing the values and would like to update another table using those values. Perhaps something like this:

```
UPDATE Table SET col1, col2
SELECT col1, col2 
FROM other_table 
WHERE sql = 'cool'
WHERE Table.id = other_table.id
```

Answer (score 6012, accepted):

```
UPDATE
    Table_A
SET
    Table_A.col1 = Table_B.col1,
    Table_A.col2 = Table_B.col2
FROM
    Some_Table AS Table_A
    INNER JOIN Other_Table AS Table_B
        ON Table_A.id = Table_B.id
WHERE
    Table_A.col3 = 'cool'
```

Comment: If you are editing the the link between tables (`SET Table.other_table_id = @NewValue`) then change the ON statement to something like `ON Table.id = @IdToEdit AND other_table.id = @NewValue`

Comment: @CharlesWood yeah. I have the same question in MySQL. It would be great if someone knows how to implement it to MySQL and share with everyone. I'm sure lots of people are looking for a MySQL version solution

Comment: How do I use an alias in set? update table set a.col1 = b.col2 from table a inner join table2 b on a.id = b.id; Instead I have to use update table set table.col1 = b.col2 from table a inner join table2 b on a.id = b.id;

Comment: Somewhat related, I often like to write my UPDATE queries as SELECT statements first so that I can see the data that will be updated before I execute. Sebastian covers a technique for this in a recent blog post: http://sqlity.net/en/2867/update-from-select/

Comment: You can't do `SET Table_A.col1 = SUM(Table_B.col1)` or any other aggregate. Jamal's answer allows you to put the aggregate in the `SELECT` https://stackoverflow.com/a/8963158/695671

Comment: For MySQL db: `UPDATE Table_A, Table_B SET Table_A.col1 = Table_B.col1
WHERE Table_A.id = Table_B.table_a_id`

Comment: This does not work for mysql. For mysql you need to make a join

Answer (score 881):

In SQL Server 2008 (or newer), use [`MERGE`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx)

```
MERGE INTO YourTable T
   USING other_table S 
      ON T.id = S.id
         AND S.tsql = 'cool'
WHEN MATCHED THEN
   UPDATE 
      SET col1 = S.col1, 
          col2 = S.col2;
```

Alternatively:

```
MERGE INTO YourTable T
   USING (
          SELECT id, col1, col2 
            FROM other_table 
           WHERE tsql = 'cool'
         ) S
      ON T.id = S.id
WHEN MATCHED THEN
   UPDATE 
      SET col1 = S.col1, 
          col2 = S.col2;
```

Comment: `MERGE` can also be used for "Upserting" records; that is, `UPDATE` if matching record exists, `INSERT` new record if no match found

Comment: This was around 10x quicker than the equivalent update...join statement for me.

Comment: MERGE can also be used to DELETE. But be careful with MERGE as the TARGET table cannot be a remote table.

Comment: Thanks for this, hadn't seen `MERGE` definitely like the syntax, and that you can use aliases (which don't work in the update/set/from) much better...  I've been using `WITH` statements for the query part.

Comment: If I can't guarantee teh results of a merge, and I can guarnatee the results of doing separate insert and update statments, then it is a bad idea to use merge.

Comment: @HLGEM: ...I assume you are aware of the case where the result of an `UPDATE..FROM` is not guaranteed? (hint: many side of a one-to-many join where the result is arbitrary) Is that the kind of 'bug' you are alluding to?

Comment: Merge bugs:

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/

Comment: @SimonD: pick any SQL Server keyword and you will find bugs. Your point? I wager there are more bugs (and more fundamental ones too) associated with `UPDATE` than `MERGE`, folks have just learned to live with them and they become part of the landscape ('features'). Consider that blogs didn't exist when `UPDATE` was the new kid on the block.

Comment: @SimonD I'm sure you would be able to find problems similar to these MERGE "bugs" (well...) in separate INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE combo. One thing - always use MERGE in SERIALIZABLE transaction (or use HOLDLOCK hint) if you want to avoid most common race conditions. Same for manual merge using INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE...

Comment: Portability note: [MERGE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_(SQL)) is ANSI SQL; [UPDATE...FROM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Update_(SQL)) is not.  Having used both, I find MERGE semantics more intelligible - I'm less likely to mess up doing a MERGE than an UPDATE...FROM.  YMMV.

Comment: Is MERGE proven to be faster than the syntax proposed in the accepted answer?

Comment: @Psychotechnopath How fast do you need it to be?

Comment: @onedaywhen I'm a data engineer so faster = always better :)

Comment: FYI, from [MERGE docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16): Performance Tip: The conditional behavior described for the MERGE statement works best when the two tables have a complex mixture of matching characteristics. For example, inserting a row if it doesn't exist, or updating a row if it matches. When simply updating one table based on the rows of another table, improve the performance and scalability with basic INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE statements.

Answer (score 855):

```sql
UPDATE YourTable 
SET Col1 = OtherTable.Col1, 
    Col2 = OtherTable.Col2 
FROM (
    SELECT ID, Col1, Col2 
    FROM other_table) AS OtherTable
WHERE 
    OtherTable.ID = YourTable.ID
```

Comment: This will tend to work across almost all DBMS which means learn once, execute everywhere.  If that is more important to you than performance you might prefer this answer, especially if your update is a one off to correct some data.

Comment: If you need to set the first table with aggregates from the second, you can put the aggregates in the select subquery, as you cannot do `SET Table_A.col1 = SUM(Table_B.col1)` (or any other aggregate function). So better than Robin Day's answer for this purpose.

Comment: I really like this solution as it feels like a natural compliment to the way `INSERT ... SELECT` works. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Thank you. this's the easiest and most understandable way.

Answer (score 310):

I'd modify [Robin's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334712/how-do-i-update-from-a-select-in-sql-server/2334741#2334741) to the following:

```
UPDATE Table
SET Table.col1 = other_table.col1,
 Table.col2 = other_table.col2
FROM
    Table
INNER JOIN other_table ON Table.id = other_table.id
WHERE
    Table.col1 != other_table.col1
OR Table.col2 != other_table.col2
OR (
    other_table.col1 IS NOT NULL
    AND Table.col1 IS NULL
)
OR (
    other_table.col2 IS NOT NULL
    AND Table.col2 IS NULL
)
```

Without a WHERE clause, you'll affect even rows that don't need to be affected, which could (possibly) cause index recalculation or fire triggers that really shouldn't have been fired.

Comment: This assumes none of the columns are nullable though.

Comment: You're right, I was typing the example by hand.  I've added a third and fourth clause to the where statement to deal with that.

Comment: `WHERE EXISTS(SELECT T1.Col1, T1.Col2 EXCEPT SELECT T2.Col1, T2.Col2))` is more concise.

Comment: Martin - it took me a while to get the knack of what that statement does.  "It's a select in a where clause but it's not a table subquery?" was a proposition I was having difficulty wrapping my brain around.  Now that I've got it, I've come to learn how valuable a technique it is, especially for some kinds of Data Warehousing operations.

Comment: shouldn't the statement also contain these two in the where clause?
     (other_table.col1 is null and table.col1 is not null) or
     (other_table.col2 is null and table.col2 is not null)

Comment: Depends on if you want to replace nulls in the destination with nulls from the source.  Frequently, I don't.  But if you do, Martin's construction of the where clause is the best thing to use.

Answer (score 232):

One way

```
UPDATE t 
SET t.col1 = o.col1, 
    t.col2 = o.col2
FROM 
    other_table o 
  JOIN 
    t ON t.id = o.id
WHERE 
    o.sql = 'cool'
```

Comment: SQL server 12. Seems like it is getting the `t.id` from `JOIN t` and not from `UPDATE t`. So it always update with the same value no matter of what row of `t` we are trying to update.

Answer (score 195):

Another possibility not mentioned yet is to just chuck the `SELECT` statement itself into a CTE and then update the CTE.

```
WITH CTE
     AS (SELECT T1.Col1,
                T2.Col1 AS _Col1,
                T1.Col2,
                T2.Col2 AS _Col2
         FROM   T1
                JOIN T2
                  ON T1.id = T2.id
         /*Where clause added to exclude rows that are the same in both tables
           Handles NULL values correctly*/
         WHERE EXISTS(SELECT T1.Col1,
                             T1.Col2
                       EXCEPT
                       SELECT T2.Col1,
                              T2.Col2))
UPDATE CTE
SET    Col1 = _Col1,
       Col2 = _Col2;
```

This has the benefit that it is easy to run the `SELECT` statement on its own first to sanity check the results, but it does requires you to alias the columns as above if they are named the same in source and target tables.

This also has the same limitation as the proprietary `UPDATE ... FROM` syntax shown in four of the other answers. If the source table is on the many side of a one-to-many join then it is undeterministic which of the possible matching joined records will be used in the `Update` (an issue that `MERGE` avoids by raising an error if there is an attempt to update the same row more than once).

Comment: is there any meaning of the name `CTE` ?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor - It is the acronym for [Common Table Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx). Just an arbitrary alias in this case.

Comment: This also works well with multiple CTEs: `;WITH SomeCompexCTE AS (...), CTEAsAbove AS (SELECT T1.Col1,... FROM T1 JOIN SomeComplexCTE...) UPDATE CTEAsAbove SET Col1=_Col1, ...`

Answer (score 143):

For the record (and others searching like I was), you can do it in MySQL like this:

```
UPDATE first_table, second_table
SET first_table.color = second_table.color
WHERE first_table.id = second_table.foreign_id
```

Answer (score 114):

Using alias:

```
UPDATE t
   SET t.col1 = o.col1
  FROM table1 AS t
         INNER JOIN 
       table2 AS o 
         ON t.id = o.id
```

Answer (score 85):

The simple way to do it is:

```
UPDATE
    table_to_update,
    table_info
SET
    table_to_update.col1 = table_info.col1,
    table_to_update.col2 = table_info.col2

WHERE
    table_to_update.ID = table_info.ID
```

Comment: This is not SQl Server syntax and it will not work in SQL server

Answer (score 76):

This may be a niche reason to perform an update (for example, mainly used in a procedure), or may be obvious to others, but it should also be stated that you can perform an update-select statement without using join (in case the tables you're updating between have no common field).

```
update
    Table
set
    Table.example = a.value
from
    TableExample a
where
    Table.field = *key value* -- finds the row in Table 
    AND a.field = *key value* -- finds the row in TableExample a
```

Comment: I feel this should be the accepted answer, because it keeps things simple and to the point.

Answer (score 69):

Here is another useful syntax:

```
UPDATE suppliers
SET supplier_name = (SELECT customers.name
                     FROM customers
                     WHERE customers.customer_id = suppliers.supplier_id)
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT customers.name
              FROM customers
              WHERE customers.customer_id = suppliers.supplier_id);
```

It checks if it is null or not by using "WHERE EXIST".

Comment: The only answer that worked for me. I'm using MariaDB, and my query is of the form: `SELECT value FROM table_1 INNER JOIN ( SELECT * FROM table_2 WHERE ..... ) ON ( ...... )`

Answer (score 63):

I add this only so you can see a quick way to write it so that you can check what will be updated before doing the update.

```
UPDATE Table 
SET  Table.col1 = other_table.col1,
     Table.col2 = other_table.col2 
--select Table.col1, other_table.col,Table.col2,other_table.col2, *   
FROM     Table 
INNER JOIN     other_table 
    ON     Table.id = other_table.id
```

Answer (score 60):

If you use [MySQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL) instead of SQL Server, the syntax is:

```sql
UPDATE Table1
INNER JOIN Table2
ON Table1.id = Table2.id
SET Table1.col1 = Table2.col1,
    Table1.col2 = Table2.col2
```

Comment: What if we want to update `Table2.col1`? how will we do that. table two is extracted on the base of the query condition.

Answer (score 59):

**UPDATE from SELECT with INNER JOIN in SQL Database**

Since there are too many replies of this post, which are most heavily up-voted, I thought I would provide my suggestion here too. Although the question is very interesting, I have seen in many forum sites and made a solution using **INNER JOIN** with screenshots.

At first, I have created a table named with **schoolold** and inserted few records with respect to their column names and execute it.

Then I executed **SELECT** command to view inserted records.

[image]

Then I created a new table named with **schoolnew** and similarly executed above actions on it.

[image]

Then, to view inserted records in it, I execute SELECT command.

[image]

Now, Here I want to make some changes in third and fourth row, to complete this action, I execute **UPDATE** command with **INNER JOIN**.

[image]

To view the changes I execute the **SELECT** command.

[image]

You can see how Third and Fourth records of table **schoolold** easily replaced with table **schoolnew** by using INNER JOIN with UPDATE statement.

Answer (score 52):

And if you wanted to join the table with itself (which won't happen too often):

```
update t1                    -- just reference table alias here
set t1.somevalue = t2.somevalue
from table1 t1               -- these rows will be the targets
inner join table1 t2         -- these rows will be used as source
on ..................        -- the join clause is whatever suits you
```

Comment: +1 but you should have used relevant alias names like `targett1` and `sourcet1` rather than (or as well as) comments.

Answer (score 50):

Updating through `CTE` is more readable than the other answers here:

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT col1,col2,id
         FROM   other_table
         WHERE  sql = 'cool')
UPDATE A
SET    A.col1 = B.col1,
       A.col2 = B.col2
FROM   table A
       INNER JOIN cte B
               ON A.id = B.id
```

Answer (score 48):

Consolidating all the different approaches here.

1. Select update
2. Update with a common table expression
3. Merge

Sample table structure is below and will update from *Product_BAK* to *Product* table.

#### Table *Product*

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Product](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](100) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

#### Table *Product_BAK*

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Product_BAK](
        [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
        [Name] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
        [Description] [nvarchar](100) NULL
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

#### 1. Select update

```
    update P1
    set Name = P2.Name
    from Product P1
    inner join Product_Bak P2 on p1.id = P2.id
    where p1.id = 2
```

#### 2. Update with a common table expression

```
    ; With CTE as
    (
        select id, name from Product_Bak where id = 2
    )
    update P
    set Name = P2.name
    from  product P  inner join CTE P2 on P.id = P2.id
    where P2.id = 2
```

#### 3. Merge

```
    Merge into product P1
    using Product_Bak P2 on P1.id = P2.id

    when matched then
    update set p1.[description] = p2.[description], p1.name = P2.Name;
```

In this *Merge* statement, we can do insert if not finding a matching record in the target, but exist in the source and please find syntax:

```
    Merge into product P1
    using Product_Bak P2 on P1.id = P2.id;

    when matched then
    update set p1.[description] = p2.[description], p1.name = P2.Name;

    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    insert (name, description)
    values(p2.name, P2.description);
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"and please find syntax"*? Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 45):

The following example uses a derived table, a SELECT statement after the FROM clause, to return the old and new values for further updates:

```
UPDATE x
SET    x.col1 = x.newCol1,
       x.col2 = x.newCol2
FROM   (SELECT t.col1,
               t2.col1 AS newCol1,
               t.col2,
               t2.col2 AS newCol2
        FROM   [table] t
               JOIN other_table t2
                 ON t.ID = t2.ID) x
```

Answer (score 44):

If you are using SQL Server you can update one table from another without specifying a join and simply link the two from the `where` clause. This makes a much simpler SQL query:

```
UPDATE Table1
SET Table1.col1 = Table2.col1,
    Table1.col2 = Table2.col2
FROM
    Table2
WHERE
    Table1.id = Table2.id
```

Answer (score 28):

The other way is to use a derived table:

```
UPDATE t
SET t.col1 = a.col1
    ,t.col2 = a.col2
FROM (
SELECT id, col1, col2 FROM @tbl2) a
INNER JOIN @tbl1 t ON t.id = a.id
```

---

Sample data

```
DECLARE @tbl1 TABLE (id INT, col1 VARCHAR(10), col2 VARCHAR(10))
DECLARE @tbl2 TABLE (id INT, col1 VARCHAR(10), col2 VARCHAR(10))

INSERT @tbl1 SELECT 1, 'a', 'b' UNION SELECT 2, 'b', 'c'

INSERT @tbl2 SELECT 1, '1', '2' UNION SELECT 2, '3', '4'

UPDATE t
SET t.col1 = a.col1
    ,t.col2 = a.col2
FROM (
SELECT id, col1, col2 FROM @tbl2) a
INNER JOIN @tbl1 t ON t.id = a.id

SELECT * FROM @tbl1
SELECT * FROM @tbl2
```

Answer (score 26):

```
UPDATE TQ
SET TQ.IsProcessed = 1, TQ.TextName = 'bla bla bla'
FROM TableQueue TQ
INNER JOIN TableComment TC ON TC.ID = TQ.TCID
WHERE TQ.IsProcessed = 0
```

To make sure you are updating what you want, select first

```
SELECT TQ.IsProcessed, 1 AS NewValue1, TQ.TextName, 'bla bla bla' AS NewValue2
FROM TableQueue TQ
INNER JOIN TableComment TC ON TC.ID = TQ.TCID
WHERE TQ.IsProcessed = 0
```

Answer (score 25):

There is even a **shorter method** and it might be surprising for you:

Sample data set:

```
CREATE TABLE #SOURCE ([ID] INT, [Desc] VARCHAR(10));
CREATE TABLE #DEST   ([ID] INT, [Desc] VARCHAR(10));

INSERT INTO #SOURCE VALUES(1,'Desc_1'), (2, 'Desc_2'), (3, 'Desc_3');
INSERT INTO #DEST   VALUES(1,'Desc_4'), (2, 'Desc_5'), (3, 'Desc_6');
```

Code:

```
UPDATE #DEST
SET #DEST.[Desc] = #SOURCE.[Desc]
FROM #SOURCE
WHERE #DEST.[ID] = #SOURCE.[ID];
```

Comment: YES - there is no JOIN on purpose and NO - this can't be applied on table variables.

Comment: I think if you use [_id] on your #SOURCE not [ID] the same as #DESTINATION's, they might let you do JOIN. "on #DESTINATION.ID=#SOURCE._id. Or even use table variable like @tbl, "on PermTable.ID=@memorytbl._id". Have you tried? I am using a phone to reply this, no computer to try.

Comment: What does this have to do with updating from a SELECT?

Comment: This is the same idea but another method - you don't have to put "select" at all to achieve JOIN and WHERE in update statement - which is SELECT type of query without even writing SELECT

Answer (score 23):

Use:

```
drop table uno
drop table dos

create table uno
(
    uid int,
    col1 char(1),
    col2 char(2)
)
create table dos
(
    did int,
    col1 char(1),
    col2 char(2),
    [sql] char(4)
)
insert into uno(uid) values (1)
insert into uno(uid) values (2)
insert into dos values (1,'a','b',null)
insert into dos values (2,'c','d','cool')

select * from uno 
select * from dos
```

EITHER:

```
update uno set col1 = (select col1 from dos where uid = did and [sql]='cool'), 
col2 = (select col2 from dos where uid = did and [sql]='cool')
```

OR:

```
update uno set col1=d.col1,col2=d.col2 from uno 
inner join dos d on uid=did where [sql]='cool'

select * from uno 
select * from dos
```

If the ID column name is the same in both tables then just put the table name before the table to be updated and use an alias for the selected table, i.e.:

```
update uno set col1 = (select col1 from dos d where uno.[id] = d.[id] and [sql]='cool'),
col2  = (select col2 from dos d where uno.[id] = d.[id] and [sql]='cool')
```

Answer (score 17):

In the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2334741/1501497), after the:

```
SET
Table_A.col1 = Table_B.col1,
Table_A.col2 = Table_B.col2
```

I would add:

```
OUTPUT deleted.*, inserted.*
```

What I usually do is putting everything in a roll backed transaction and using the `"OUTPUT"`: in this way I see everything that is about to happen. When I am happy with what I see, I change the `ROLLBACK` into `COMMIT`.

I usually need to document what I did, so I use the `"results to Text"` option when I run the roll-backed query and I save both the script and the result of the OUTPUT. (Of course this is not practical if I changed too many rows)

Answer (score 14):

The below solution works for a MySQL database:

```
UPDATE table1 a , table2 b 
SET a.columname = 'some value' 
WHERE b.columnname IS NULL ;
```

Answer (score 14):

```
UPDATE table AS a
INNER JOIN table2 AS b
ON a.col1 = b.col1
INNER JOIN ... AS ...
ON ... = ...
SET ...
WHERE ...
```

Answer (score 13):

The other way to update from a select statement:

```
UPDATE A
SET A.col = A.col,B.col1 = B.col1
FROM  first_Table AS A
INNER JOIN second_Table AS B  ON A.id = B.id WHERE A.col2 = 'cool'
```

Comment: This answer turned up in the low quality review queue, presumably because you don't provide any explanation of the code. If this code answers the question, consider adding adding some text explaining the code in your answer. This way, you are far more likely to get more upvotes — and help the questioner learn something new.

Answer (score 10):

Option 1: Using Inner Join:

```
UPDATE
    A
SET
    A.col1 = B.col1,
    A.col2 = B.col2
FROM
    Some_Table AS A
    INNER JOIN Other_Table AS B
        ON A.id = B.id
WHERE
    A.col3 = 'cool'
```

Option 2: Co related Sub query

```
UPDATE table 
SET Col1 = B.Col1, 
    Col2 = B.Col2 
FROM (
    SELECT ID, Col1, Col2 
    FROM other_table) B
WHERE 
    B.ID = table.ID
```

Comment: Did it work for you? I used exact same query but had errors when used inner join, alias coun't be resolved.
However the co-related sub query worked perfectly.

Comment: I don't have the exact error logs but the alias A was being referenced before the assignment, which caused the error.

Comment: I used the correlated sub query

Comment: What was this tested on? [SQL Server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server)? [MySQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL)? Something else? What version?

Answer (score 10):

```
UPDATE table1
SET column1 = (SELECT expression1
               FROM table2
               WHERE conditions)
[WHERE conditions];
```

The syntax for the UPDATE statement when updating one table with data from another table in SQL Server.

Answer (score 7):

It is important to point out, as others have, that [MySQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL) or [MariaDB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MariaDB) use a different syntax. Also it supports a very convenient USING syntax (in contrast to T/SQL). Also INNER JOIN is synonymous with JOIN. Therefore the query in the original question would be best implemented in MySQL thusly:

```
UPDATE
    Some_Table AS Table_A

JOIN
    Other_Table AS Table_B USING(id)

SET
    Table_A.col1 = Table_B.col1,
    Table_A.col2 = Table_B.col2

WHERE
    Table_A.col3 = 'cool'
```

I've not seen the a solution to the asked question in the other answers, hence my two cents.
*(tested on PHP 7.4.0 MariaDB 10.4.10)*

Comment: Re *"the query in the original question"*: What? The very first revision was tagged with SQL Server (the Microsoft product).

Comment: NATURAL joins with or without USING is an evil feature and can conducts to false answer and catatsrophic response times...

Comment: @PeterMortensen hence my disclaimer right at the start.

Comment: @SQLpro please elaborate

Comment: @theking2 A little bit too complex to answer in few words, but I demonstrate why in my new book about SQL language (in French) that will be available for free in few month on developpez.com website

Comment: @SQLpro cool. I've not witnessed any _catastrophic response times_ for this type of update in my 40-year carrier as a (db) developer.

Comment: @theking2 I am 63 years old and almost 40 in RDBMS... and also teach in engineers schools and professionals (like for the "République de Genève" in 2020 for SQL Server). The reason why the NATURAL JOIN is evil is that the SQL ISO standard does not indicate how to proceed in the case of multiple joins with the same column name if there is more than one join... and the optimizer can have a false or duplicate joins that can drive to a tringale join or more !

Answer (score 5):

You can use from this for update in SQL Server:

```
UPDATE
    T1
SET
   T1.col1 = T2.col1,
   T1.col2 = T2.col2
FROM
   Table1 AS T1
INNER JOIN Table2 AS T2
    ON T1.id = T2.id
WHERE
    T1.col3 = 'cool'
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"use from this for update"* (seems incomprehesible)? Are "from" and/or "update" literal (SQL) or not? Can you [fix](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52119749/edit) it? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question/answer should appear as if it was written today.)

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @tblStudent table (id int,name varchar(300))
declare @tblMarks table (std_id int,std_name varchar(300),subject varchar(50),marks int)

insert into @tblStudent Values (1,'Abdul')
insert into @tblStudent Values(2,'Rahim')

insert into @tblMarks Values(1,'','Math',50)
insert into @tblMarks Values(1,'','History',40)
insert into @tblMarks Values(2,'','Math',30)
insert into @tblMarks Values(2,'','history',80)


select * from @tblMarks

update m
set m.std_name=s.name
 from @tblMarks as m
left join @tblStudent as s on s.id=m.std_id

select * from @tblMarks
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? What was it tested on? What version of SQL Server? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52702201/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 1):

Works for me well with SQLite3, update rows with SELECT after INNER SELECT.

```
UPDATE clients
SET col1 = '2023-02-02 18:51:30.826621'
FROM (
      SELECT * FROM clients dc WHERE dc.phone NOT IN (
               SELECT do.phone FROM dclient_order do WHERE do.order_date > '2023-01-01' GROUP BY do.phone
               )
      ) NewTable
WHERE clients.phone = NewTable.phone;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using INSERT SELECT before. For those who want to use new stuff here is a solution that works similarly, but it is much shorter:

```
UPDATE table1                                          // Table that's going to be updated.
LEFT JOIN                                              // Type of join.
    table2 AS tb2                                      // Second table and rename for easy.
ON
    tb2.filedToMatchTables = table1.fieldToMatchTables // Fields to connect both tables.
SET
    fieldFromTable1 = tb2.fieldFromTable2;             // Field to be updated on table1.

    field1FromTable1 = tb2.field1FromTable2,           // This is in the case you need to
    field1FromTable1 = tb2.field1FromTable2,           // update more than one field.
    field1FromTable1 = tb2.field1FromTable2;           // Remember to put ; at the end.
```

Answer (score -1):

**Best practices: Update rows and save in SQL Server used in the company**

```
 WITH t AS
         (
           SELECT UserID, EmailAddress, Password, Gender, DOB, Location,
           Active  FROM Facebook.Users
         )
 UPDATE t SET Active = 0
```

It is the safest way to update the records, and this is how you can see what we are going to update.
Source: [URL](https://www.iodocs.com/best-practice-update-rows-on-sql-server/)

Comment: The first line is incomprehensible. Can you [fix](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69340889/edit) it?

Answer (score -1):

```
 UPDATE 
     A
 SET
     A.col1 = B.col1,
     A.col2 = B.col2
 FROM
     Some_Table AS A
     INNER JOIN Other_Table AS B
         ON A.id = B.id
 WHERE
     A.col3 = 'cool'
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score -1):

**

### BEWARE OF UPDATE WITH JOINS.... This can lead to divergent and uncontrollable results!

**

All solution of the form of :

```
UPDATE ... SET ... FROM ... JOIN ...
```

Cna have different results according to the physical model of the database... Let's see a demo (for MS SQL Server):

**1 - the tables**

```
CREATE TABLE T_US_PRESIDENT_USP 
(USP_ID           INT PRIMARY KEY,
 USP_FIRST_NAME   VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
 USP_SECOND_NAME  VARCHAR(25));

CREATE TABLE T_US_PRESIDENT_LAST_NAMES_PLN 
(PLN_ID           INT PRIMARY KEY,
 USP_ID           INT NOT NULL REFERENCES T_US_PRESIDENT_USP (USP_ID),
 USP_LAST_NAME   VARCHAR(25));

INSERT INTO T_US_PRESIDENT_USP (USP_ID, USP_FIRST_NAME) VALUES 
(1, 'ROOSEVELT'), (2, 'EISENHOWER'), (3, 'KENNEDY');

INSERT INTO T_US_PRESIDENT_LAST_NAMES_PLN (PLN_ID, USP_ID, USP_LAST_NAME) VALUES 
(101, 1, 'Franklin'), (102, 1, 'Delano'), 
(201, 2, 'Dwight'),   (202, 2, 'David'),
(301, 3, 'John'),     (302, 3, 'Fitzgerald');
```

**2 - A first UPDATE JOIN query :**

```
UPDATE T
SET    USP_SECOND_NAME =  USP_LAST_NAME 
FROM   T_US_PRESIDENT_USP AS T
       JOIN T_US_PRESIDENT_LAST_NAMES_PLN AS N
          ON T.USP_ID = N.USP_ID;
```

What does the T_US_PRESIDENT_USP table contain?

```
SELECT * FROM T_US_PRESIDENT_USP;

USP_ID      USP_FIRST_NAME      USP_SECOND_NAME
----------- ------------------- -------------------
1           ROOSEVELT           Franklin
2           EISENHOWER          Dwight
3           KENNEDY             John
```

Now, adding an index to speed up the UPDATE :

```
CREATE INDEX X ON T_US_PRESIDENT_LAST_NAMES_PLN (USP_LAST_NAME, USP_ID);
```

**3 - A second UPDATE JOIN query (with is just absolutly the same as 2...):**

```
UPDATE T
SET    USP_SECOND_NAME =  USP_LAST_NAME 
FROM   T_US_PRESIDENT_USP AS T
       JOIN T_US_PRESIDENT_LAST_NAMES_PLN AS N
          ON T.USP_ID = N.USP_ID;
```

What does the T_US_PRESIDENT_USP table contain?

```
SELECT * FROM T_US_PRESIDENT_USP;

USP_ID      USP_FIRST_NAME      USP_SECOND_NAME
----------- ------------------- -------------------------
1           ROOSEVELT           *Delano*
2           EISENHOWER          Dwight
3           KENNEDY             *Fitzgerald*
```

As you see the results between UPDATE 1 and UPDATE 2 has change because of the index !

### So avoid using JOINs in UPDATES !

Comment: The problem isn't the use of the `JOIN` keyword. The issue is that you are joining onto a source which has a "many" relationship to the target. If you want deterministic results you should ensure you are joining onto a source that is deterministic, potentially by applying aggregation or row numbering or some other way of being specific about selecting the specific value you actually want applied per USP_ID. In this case the `T_US_PRESIDENT_LAST_NAMES_PLN` table is not fit for the purpose as it does not provide any information about the name ordering

Comment: Of course, but you must remember that RDBMS has been espacially designed to avoid the mix of logical and physical point of view... You have not to understand the underlying facts about the database sets to apply any query thta will give unconsistent results. It is why this syntax is prohibited in ISO standard SQL...

Comment: This is nothing to do with "physical". It is entirely logical. The syntax isn't prohibited. It just isn't part of the standard. There is nothing in the standard that forbids vendors from implementing this. `MERGE`  would throw an error in this case of the many to one relationship but you still have the problem that you need to do the same aggregation or row numbering or have some way of reducing it down from a "many" relationship first. Which there is no sensible way of doing with your `T_US_PRESIDENT_LAST_NAMES_PLN` design that will give the correct result

Comment: So both `MERGE` and `UPDATE   ... JOIN` need up front consideration of whether the source has a many relationship or not. Otherwise with the `UPDATE`  you can end up with undeterministic behaviour as to which of the "many" is selected and with `MERGE` you are protected from that but can end up with runtime errors if you omit to consider this ("The MERGE statement attempted to UPDATE or DELETE the same row more than once")

Comment: Yes UPDATE with MERGE statement will raise this case and throw an exception, that the UPDATE JOIN has not been designed for...  and contrary to what you say, it is indeed a case of mixing physical and logical aspects to see that a query result can change depending on the indexing which is a physical object. This was also recalled by Franck Edgar Codd himself in his rule 9 “Logical Data Independence”. See "The Relational Model for Database management" v2 F. E. Codd, p 347 et seq...

Answer (score -2):

The same solution can be written in a slightly different way as I would like to set the columns only once. I have written about both the tables. It is working in [MySQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL).

```
UPDATE Table t,
(SELECT col1, col2 FROM other_table WHERE sql = 'cool' ) o
SET t.col1 = o.col1, t.col2=o.col2
WHERE t.id = o.id
```

Answer (score -4):

Like this; but you must be sure to update the table and table after from have be the same.

```
UPDATE Table SET col1, col2
FROM table
inner join other_table Table.id = other_table.id
WHERE sql = 'cool'
```

Comment: This syntax is not correct. Could you edit your answer to show us what you mean?

Comment: This is partly incomprehensible. Can you [fix](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53425369/edit) it?

Answer (score -4):

Oracle SQL (use an alias):

```
UPDATE Table T 
SET T.col1 = (SELECT OT.col1 WHERE OT.id = T.id),
T.col2 = (SELECT OT.col2 WHERE OT.id = T.id);
```