# Copy data from a column in some rows to another column in other rows in oracle

Tags: oracle

quite the same question as here : [Copy data from one existing row to another existing row in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/663154/copy-data-from-one-existing-row-to-another-existing-row-in-sql)

but in Oracle, where `update ... from` and `update t1, t2` are not supported.

I'll repeat it here in my own words ;
I have a table T, which looks like this :

[image: table]

and as the arrow shows it, I want to copy everything from r where c = 1 to e where c = 2, with t matching.

I have the select statement to get what I want to copy :

```
select 
  told.t, 
  told.r
from 
  T told 
  inner join 
  T tnew
on 
  told.t= tnew.t
where 
  told.c = 1
  and 
  tnew.c = 2
```

I just don't know how to put this together in an update. An Oracle update, specifically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
update T tnew
set tnew.e = (select told.r from T told where told.c = 2 and told.t = tnew.t)
where tnew.c = 1
```

Comment: Well... thanks. It seems a lot easier now that I know the answer !

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the time for a bulk collects! Not as pretty as AB Cade's solution but more efficient.

```
declare

  c_data is
   select t1.rowid as rid, t2.r
     from my_table t1
     join my_table t2
       on t1.t = t2.t
    where t1.c = 2
      and t2.c = 1
          ;

   type t__data is table of c_data index by binary_integer;
   t_data t__data;

begin

   open c_data;
   loop

      fetch c_data bulk collect into t_data limit 25000;

      exit when t_data.count = 0;

      forall i in t_data.first .. t_data.last loop
         update my_table
            set e = t_data(i).r
          where rowid = t_data(i).rid
                ;

      commit;

   end loop;
   close c_data;

end;
/
```