# Is UPDATE SET FROM syntax supported in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql-update

We have table `t_post` and table `t_post_like`.

`t_post` has a column called `like_count`, which stores how many likes it got.

Every time a user likes the post, a new row will created in `t_post_like`, each row contains the post's id in column `post_id`. the `like_count` field in `t_post` will increase by 1 as well.

Now we wish to correct the `like_count` in t_post with this SQL that I found in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13881782/986966):

```
update p
set p.like_count = l.like_count_by_post 
 from t_post p inner join 
(
    select post_id, count(1) like_count_by_post
    from t_post_like
    group by post_id
) l
on p.id = l.post_id;
```

But we got error `right syntax to use near 'from t_post c inner join...`, Is the `update set from` syntax not supported in MySQL?

Comment: There is no t_circle table in your query!

Comment: It was a mistake, I have corrected it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL does support an update join syntax, but it would look more like this:

```sql
UPDATE t_post p
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT post_id, COUNT(*) like_count_by_post
    FROM t_post_like
    GROUP BY post_id
) l
    ON l.post_id = p.id
SET
    like_count = l.like_count_by_post;
```

Comment: So I guess the syntax I used was considered not recognizable by MySQL then?

Comment: [You were using SQL Server update join syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982919/sql-update-query-using-joins), apparently.

Comment: I had no idea it was a SQL server syntax. I really hope that we can learn the syntax once and apply to all SQL databases. Instead of learning a syntax for each DB.

Comment: @fall yeah, this has been a dream for most sql developers for a long-long time...